# Smooth animation of UITableView when removing section

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uitableview

### tl;dr

When deleting a section in a UITableView while the scroll offset is somewhere in the middle of the table the flow of animation goes like this -

1. The contentOffset is set to (0,0) immediately (no animation, just pops up)
2. The section fades away nicely

I'd like to make this animation flow a bit better - fade away the section and only afterwards (or simultaneously in a smooth way) scroll the "dead zone" of the table back up.

### A bit more explaining

I'm using NSFetchedResultsController as a data source for UITableView to display rows and update the table when changes occur in the NSManagedObjectContext - like this (I removed unrelated code) -

```
- (void)controller: (NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject: (id)anObject
       atIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType: (NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableController.tableView;
    switch(type) {
         ....
         NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
         break;
         ...    
    }        
}
```

I got all the boilerplate of `controllerWillChangeContent` and `controllerDidChangeContent`, the result of this code is that if all the rows in a specific section are removed - the section is also removed.

The problem (as I specified in the tl;dr section) is that the animation doesn't work as expected - 
If the section removal happen while scrolled half-way into the removed section, the scroll content changed immediately and the section fades away, which looks pretty broken.

Anyone ever stumbled on a situation like this? I'm sure I can narrow it down to a generic problem without using NSFetchedResultsController, that's jus the code I'm currently using.

I'd gladly add more information if needed.

Thanks!

### Update 1

So after a bit playing with the contentOffset manually I can get something partly working when doing this flow -

1. When the `NSFetchedResultsController` calls `controllerWillChangeContent` I save the UITableView contentOffset (before `beginUpdates`)
2. When the `controllerDidChangeContent` is called and right after I call `endUpdates` I save the contentOffset of the table (this is the offset that wasn't animated)
3. I scroll back to the original contentOffset I saved in part 1 and use `[tableView setContentOffset:offsetAfterEndUpdates animated:YES]` to scroll to the new offset

This **cannot** be the best solution / what Apple ment.

Comment: the normal tableView behavior is: The contentOffset remains as it is (if possible), else it is animated to the new (smaller) value. Within the same Animation-Block the Section/Rows are removed with the specified `UITableViewRowAnimation`. So Either the `NSFetchedResultsController` is messing up this behavior or some of your code does.

Comment: That's interesting, I'd take a closer look at the code and see if I mess the default animation somehow

Answer (score 0):

A `UITableViewDelegate` is also conform to `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol so you could delay that section removal action to

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // try to perform your action here, 
    // for instance you could re-attach your NSFetchedResultController delegate here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach that works (at least in my experience) is to a) delete the section and b) don't delete the individual rows.

For reference, take a look at the [`TLIndexPathUpdates`](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/TLIndexPathTools/Data%20Models/TLIndexPathUpdates.m) initializer in [TLIndexPathTools](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools). It calculates batch updates and I think it works well for the scenario you've described.

Answer (score 0):

Okay!

So after intensive digging I found that the problem lies in my code (like I was commented right after posting). Was pretty hard to find but somewhere between the beginUpdates and endUpdates I change the UITableView footer view, that messes with the contentOffset animation.

So that's it, my fault, not Apple.

Thanks for the help Jonathan Cichon!